# Use multipart data in html form

Tags: php, html, forms, multipartform-data

Is it possible to set html form input value as multipart data ?

I'm trying to make an image-ready to upload while submitting an HTML form ( remote image data generated by PHP)

Something like this

```
<form action="http://remote_site.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" value="#Multipart/binary data used here (??)#">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FormData API using a Blob in [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2).

```
var formData = new FormData();

// JavaScript file-like object...
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

Some docs at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

*Sorry, misunderstood before!*

Comment: This is not what I'm asking at all, I'm asking I want to manually insert binary multipart data into form without asking user to select a file, its my own generated binary i'd like to use while submitting.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you before. Hope this helps